# Convert categorical data back to numbers using keras utils to_categorical

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am using `to_categorical` from `keras.utils` for one-hot encoding the numbers in a list. How can get back the numbers from categorical data? Is there any function available for that.

```
Y=to_categorical(y, num_classes=79)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it simply by [`np.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
import numpy as np
y = [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5]
Y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=len(y))
print(Y)
y = np.argmax(Y, axis=-1)
print(y)
# [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5]
```

---

*Why use `argmax(axis=-1)`?*

In the above example, `to_categorical` returns a matrix with shape (6,6). Set `axis=-1` means, extract largest indices in each row.

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

See more at [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) about indexing.

*What if my data have more than 1 dimension?*

No difference. Each entry, in the preliminary list, converts to a one-hot encoding with the size of `[1, nb_classes]` which only one index is one and the rest are zero. Similar to the above example, when you find the maximum in each row, it converts to the original list.

```
y = [[0, 1], [2, 0], [4, 5]]
Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=6)

#[[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
#
# [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
#
# [[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]]

y = np.argmax(Y, axis=-1)

#[[0 1]
# [2 0]
# [4 5]]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Amir. could you explain me the why the value of axis is -1?

Comment: ok, that's good. if the shape of Y is three dimensional. In that situation how can we calculate the axis

Comment: No difference... set the axis to -1.